# Help understanding lichess puzzle 274165037

Tags: puzzles

Link to puzzle:
https://lichess.org/training/274165037

I got the correct solution first try, but I don't understand what it accomplishes. Seems the king can escape via f2 and rook h1 should deal with the pawn push

```
[Title "Lichess puzzle"]
[fen "2kr3r/ppq2pp1/3b4/2p1n1P1/2P1N2p/P2P3K/1PQ1N3/R1B2R2 b - - 0 1"]

1...Qd7+ 2. Kg2 Qg4+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: After completing the puzzle you can turn on the engine by clicking on the toggle on the top right corner of the move list. You can try different moves and see what the best moves are in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rh1 in response to h3 by black just loses the rook after Qg2+. White has to move a knight to g3 to try and stop the pawn queening but then black starts a king hunt with Qf3+ which leads to mate.

```
[Title "Lichess puzzle"]
[fen "2kr3r/ppq2pp1/3b4/2p1n1P1/2P1N2p/P2P3K/1PQ1N3/R1B2R2 b - - 0 1"]

1...Qd7+ 2. Kg2 Qg4+ 3. Kf2 h3 4. Rh1 (4. N2g3 Qf3+ 5. Ke1 Nxd3+ 6. Kd2 Bf4+ 7. Kc3 Nf2+ 8. Be3 Qxe3 9. Qd3 Qxd3#) Qg2+
```

Comment: h3 is OK, but Nxd3+ instead (Qxd3 Bg3+) is more forcing. I see Kh1 instead of Kf2 as more stubborn.

Comment: Makes sense. First time I've encountered a puzzle as cryptic as this one, are they common at all? They usually result in either mate or a material advantage

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple puzzle that wants you to correctly steer into the most forcing line, seizing an attack. It is not a study that wants you to find a nice, unique solution down every line.

**What it does say**:

Your opponent has not realized they had to play d4 in order to open the diagonal for their queen to gain access to f5.

Do you realize you have a winning position at hand?

Do you realize you have to start with Qd7+ immediately?

**What it doesn't say**:

Can you force a way to always at least win white's queen for a knight? (Hint: white has to take black's knight with their queen to avoid checkmate!)